# MVC ajax dropdownlist url change

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am new in ajax and I need a help.
This is a script that populates second dropdownlist once first is selected.
It works fine using GetStates action that gets data from database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CountriyID").change(function () {
        var abbr = $("#CountriyID").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/SetUp/GetStates",
            data: { countryCode: abbr },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            error: function () {
                alert("An error occurred.");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var items = "";
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
                });

                $("#StateID").html(items);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Here is the view that I am working on

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "SetUp", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="action:AddCity" value="Add" />
    </form>
    <div class="editor-field">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountriyID, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "ID", "Text"))</div>
     <div class="editor-field">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateID, new SelectList(Model.States, "ID", "Text"))</div>
}
```

If I need to add a City I click on a submit button and it goes to correct action.
The problem happened when I populate dropdownlist. After population, the City button do not respond anymore.  It looks like the url get stack at "/SetUp/GetStates" and I cannot do any actions anymore on my form.

Please Let me know what am I doing wrong and where to take a look?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below code hope it helps you:

```
<form action="" method="post">

    <div class="editor-field">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountriyID, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "ID", "Text"))</div>
     <div class="editor-field">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateID, new SelectList(Model.States, "ID", "Text"))</div>

<input type="submit" name="action:AddCity" value="Add" />
    </form>
```

As the drop down must come into the  tags and submit must be at the last place in the  tags ideally.